# Debezium efficiency with high mutation frequencies

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium, oracle-cdc

I'm creating a stream from Oracle through Kafka to Azure and am wondering if Debezium is any good for that. It seems to fit the bill but when I look at the data sent through Kafka I'm worried about the efficiency. The packets don't seem to be lean-and-mean but quite large.

Does anybody have experience with a setup with about 4000 mutations/sec over a line from on-prem to Azure? The line is about 500Mbit but is shared with others...

I am leaning towards using my own simple format to transport the packets to Azure and only over there convert them to Debezium for ingestion in the rest of the pipeline.

Thanks,
Milo

Comment: What do you mean high mutation frequencies? Does the DDL change 4000 times a second?

Comment: Nope, there are about 4000 database content mutations like insert, update and delete per second that need to be transferred.

Comment: 4k transactions/s is not very high rate. I don't know about performance of Debezium, but you can try with OpenLogReplicator. My laptop can handled without problems much bigger load and the latency is relatively small.

Comment: Nice idea the OpenLogReplicator but a bit scary. Is the format of the logfiles well documented by Oracle? I don't think they guarantee anything about the format of the log files. I am currently using logminer what makes use of a never ending SELECT statement to the database. But that is deprecated and removed as of version 19. So reading the logfiles directly would be nice.

Comment: None software vendor is giving any guarantee. Even if you have payed support - the bugs you find might not get fixed. It is just a matter of valuating risk and matching a best solution based on your business requirements and budget.